# Unix (Tru64): how to calculate files sizes?

Tags: command-line, unix

I would like to extract files from

```
ls -la
```

based on certain creation year (e.g. 1999), and then calcute the file size of these files. How to accomplish that?

Comment: Do you mean the sum of all sizes?

Comment: The size of the files is given by ls. Do you mean, you want to sum the total size of these files?

Comment: Yes, I mean total file size of these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't think the version of `find` in Tru64 supports the same options that GNU `find` does and there doesn't seem to be a `stat`, you'll probably have to parse `ls` which is [generally discouraged](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

This should work, but you'll need to adjust the field numbers to match the way your `ls` output is laid out.

```
ls -lA | awk '$8==1999 {total += $5} END{print "Total: " total}'
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `ls -lA --time-style=+%Y` to ensure that the year is shown, and to hide `.` and `..`.

Comment: @cYrus: Except that, since Tru64 is not a GNU system, it doesn't have `--time-style`.

Comment: Ok for that, but using the `-a` option instead of `-A` you'll count the size of the directories `.` and `..` too. Unless Tru64 doesn't behave differently...

Comment: @cYrus: You are correct concerning the `-A`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I would write `LC_ALL=C ls -lA`, to avoid date formats that don't show the year in the same position. @atricapilla: note that if there are any subdirectories, this will count the size of the directory entry (*not* the size or number of the files in the subdirectory); add `/^-/ && ` at the beginning of the awk script to only count regular files.